# The import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, maven, jar, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am naive to StanfordNlpTagger.
I have downloaded the JAR files form 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download.

I have include the four jar files

Satnford-postagger.jar

Stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar

Stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar-javadoc.jar

Stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar-src.jar

The main problem is that I am not able to "import the edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP". Can anyone please suggest me if any more jar files have to included?

Thank you.

Comment: The -javadoc and -src jar files are unnecessary.  Also, is it `Satnford-postagger` or `Stanford-psotagger` or some other permutation?

Answer (score 1):

That class is in a different jar file that you didn't download:

```
stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jim. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: I have redefined my error at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206095/error-in-creating-the-stanfordcorenlp-object . Can u please give valuable suggestions?

Comment: You must download that jar and include it in your classpath as well as `stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar`.

Comment: I have downloaded the jar and included both the jar files in my classpath. but still i am facing one more problem, which i have rephrased in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206095/error-in-creating-the-stanfordcorenlp-object. Can u please verify it and let me know? Thans for ur reply.