# Error in creating the StanfordCoreNLP object

Tags: java, maven, jar, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have downloaded and installed required jar files from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download.

I have include the five jar files

Satnford-postagger.jar

Stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar

Stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar-javadoc.jar

Stanford-psotagger-3.3.1.jar-src.jar

stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar

and the code is

```
public class lemmafirst {

    protected StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public lemmafirst() {
        // Create StanfordCoreNLP object properties, with POS tagging
        // (required for lemmatization), and lemmatization
        Properties props;
        props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");

        /*
         * This is a pipeline that takes in a string and returns various analyzed linguistic forms. 
         * The String is tokenized via a tokenizer (such as PTBTokenizerAnnotator), 
         * and then other sequence model style annotation can be used to add things like lemmas, 
         * POS tags, and named entities. These are returned as a list of CoreLabels. 
         * Other analysis components build and store parse trees, dependency graphs, etc. 
         * 
         * This class is designed to apply multiple Annotators to an Annotation. 
         * The idea is that you first build up the pipeline by adding Annotators, 
         * and then you take the objects you wish to annotate and pass them in and 
         * get in return a fully annotated object.
         * 
         *  StanfordCoreNLP loads a lot of models, so you probably
         *  only want to do this once per execution
         */
        ***this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);***
}
```

My Problem is in creating a the pipline.

The ERROR that i got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:563)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:262)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
    at lemmafirst.<init>(lemmafirst.java:39)
    at lemmafirst.main(lemmafirst.java:83)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:758)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:289)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:253)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:88)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:76)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:561)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:434)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:753)
    ... 11 more
```

Can anyone please correct the errors? Thank you

Answer (score 15):

The exception which is thrown is due to the missing pos model. This is because there are downloadable versions with and without the model files.

Either you add
stanford-postagger-**full**-3.3.1.jar
which can be found on the following page (stanford-postagger-full-2014-01-04.zip):
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml
.

Or you do the same for the whole CoreNLP Package (stanford-corenlp-**full**....jar):
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml
(Then you can drop all the postagger depenedencies too, they are included in CoreNLP)

In case you only want to add the model files, look at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C304725258) and download "stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar".

Comment: Short answer: Download the full CoreNLP package, which includes the model files, from here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar and it worked for me. Thanks Chirtopher..

Comment: I tried this and didn't work for some reason. I then used jarsplice to splice my jar and the ..-models.jar and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

An easier way to add those model files is to simply add following dependencies in your pom.xml and let maven manage it for you:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
  <classifier>models</classifier> <!--  will get the dependent model jars -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sruthi Poddutur for you comment. It helps resolving my isssue.

Comment: For gradle, what should I write in build.gradle?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone looking for gradle dependencies, add the following under dependencies.

```
 compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.9.1'
 compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.9.1', classifier: 'models'
```