# Error when using StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford CoreNLP as a library in my java program. I use IntelliJ as the IDE.
I was trying to test the library, so I wrote this code:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by Benjamin on 15/5/4.
 */
public class SentimentAnaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }
}
```

and it shows the error like this:

```
Adding annotator tokenize
TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:292)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:289)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:126)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:122)
    at SentimentAnaTest.main(SentimentAnaTest.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:770)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:298)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:263)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:97)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:77)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(AnnotatorImplementations.java:59)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:290)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:481)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:765)
    ... 16 more
```

I read a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206095/error-in-creating-the-stanfordcorenlp-object) but couldn't figure out what the problem was, because I added the library from the Maven Central Repository which already included the "stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar".

From the error message it seemed like the program was trying to load a file from `edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger` so I download the tagger file from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) and put it into `/edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger`. However it still didn't work.

Can someone tell me whats this error is about and help me to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tagger file has to be placed into your project root.

```
project
-- src --> SentimentAnaTest
-- english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
```

Tested in Eclipse project.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Fixed using:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

or for SBT:

```
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.2",
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.2" classifier "models",
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are starting server via the jar file that you must have created from the compiled classed, so make sure you re-create the jar after putting in the required file to the folder location as can be seen on the error console.
Once you re-create the jar, start the server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and took me a long time to figure it out. Essentially there are two main jar files we will be needing to solve the error. One is the stable version 3.6.0 and the current version 3.7.0

So, download both jar files from the following [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-english-kbp-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar) and [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-2017-04-14-build.jar). Now extract both the jar files. The extracted folder of the 3.7.0 jar file does not have the models folder as of now. You can find this folder in the 3.6.0 jar file extracted folder.

Copy that folder from 3.6 version to 3.7 version.

Now from the root folder run the following command:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

It should run perfectly. In order to use the server, follow this [py-corenlp](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp)